# Update Sql Table By Listview Items

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, listview

My listview has three columns and rows as below:

```
Trans ID                Name         Amount
1                       mahesh      1000
2                       mahendra    2000
3                       kirti       3000
```

Is there possible to update/insert/delete on sql table  like below:

1. Delete from mytable where transID = 3
2. Update mytable set name = ‘mahendra’  where transID=2
3. Insert into mytable(transID,name,amount)values(@transID,@name,@amount)

Is it possible The above three sql transact statement  with Listview?.

I am Looking For Code Example Here.

Comment: ASP.NET? Win Forms? MVC? Are you looking for a yes/no answer, or code examples?

Comment: options for ways to do this vary between ASP.NET and Winforms and such.  For example, in ASP.NET ListView is a DataBoundControl, but I don't believe it is in WinForms.  OR are you looking for the T-SQL statements themselves?

Comment: @Tim, very true but I am here asking for any suggestion or solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean is update the DB Table by your listview ... 
I think it is like  ↓

```
 1) delete from yourtable where transid in (all ids in your listview);
 2) foreach(var item in listview.Items)  Insert into yourtable(transID,name,amount)values(@transID,@name,@amount)
```

Comment: I wants to delete the records on specific ID not by all and another thing how to provide or supply value of listview columns as per declared parameter.